# python3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SpeechRecognition'

Tags: python, pip, speech-recognition

I am trying to use this module, but it always says that its not installed. I am trying to run the file with python3 and installed it with pip3. pip3 list shows it. No idea why it doesn't work.

import in code:
`import Speech_recognition as sr`

Comment: Seems to be a case error: try `speech_recognition`

Answer (score 0):

Try `import speech_recognition as sr`. If that doesn't work, try `sudo pip3 install` the module.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work tho :( No Idea what to do.

Comment: What about giving us the error/code?